# "clearTimeout is not defined" in tsc.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I have an Electron app that uses TSC during the compilation process to apparently transpile some TypeScript. However, I am getting a `Uncaught ReferenceError: clearTimeout is not defined` whenever running the Electron app. How would I fix this? I have supposedly updated TSC and Typescript through NPM. Any help on diagnosing the problem would be great. Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you supplied the code that exhibited the error as it is hard to reproduce exactly what is happening without it.

Comment: https://github.com/theblacksmith/typescript-require/issues/48